# cannot find module electron updater

Tags: typescript, electron

I encountered cannot find module electron updater error.

- Electron-Builder Version: 22.11.7
- Node Version: 14.17.4
- Electron Version: 12.0.9
- Electron-updater: 5.2.1
- Target: windows

I installed electron-updater to dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
        "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
         ...
        "electron-updater": "^5.2.1",
```

And I used electron updater to typescript.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } from "electron";
import { autoUpdater } from "electron-updater";
```

So when I built typescript, There is no error. But I executed the app, the error occurred. So I try to fix some code. This is orignal code. I removed the !node_modules. After that, there is no error.

```
        "files": [
            "desktop/*",
            "build/**/*",
            "build-desktop/**/*",
            "!node_modules"
        ],
```

But I don't want to add node_modules because the app size is increased.
This is log that gets with tsc --traceResolution option. As you can see the log, when build time, electron-updater is found.
But why can not found the module on runtime?

```
======== Resolving module 'electron-updater' from 'D:/DI/front-end/desktop/main.ts'. ========
Resolving real path for 'D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/main.d.ts', result 'D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/main.d.ts'.
======== Module name 'electron-updater' was successfully resolved to 'D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-upd
```

This list is tsc compiled files that gets with--listFiles option.
build command is

```
tsc desktop/main.ts --skipLibCheck --target es5 --outDir build-desktop --esModuleInterop
```

```
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/AppAdapter.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/DownloadedUpdateHelper.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/electronHttpExecutor.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/providers/Provider.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/typed-emitter/index.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/AppUpdater.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/BaseUpdater.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/AppImageUpdater.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/MacUpdater.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/NsisUpdater.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/node_modules/electron-updater/out/main.d.ts
D:/DI/front-end/desktop/socketClient.ts
```

I checked the npm ls --production, it has electron-updater.

```
+-- electron-updater@5.2.1
| +-- @types/semver@7.3.12
| +-- builder-util-runtime@9.0.3
| | +-- debug@4.3.4
| | | `-- ms@2.1.2 deduped
| | `-- sax@1.2.4
| +-- fs-extra@10.1.0
| | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.6
| | +-- jsonfile@6.1.0
| | | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.6 deduped
| | | `-- universalify@2.0.0 deduped
| | `-- universalify@2.0.0
| +-- js-yaml@4.1.0
| | `-- argparse@2.0.1
| +-- lazy-val@1.0.5
| +-- lodash.escaperegexp@4.1.2
| +-- lodash.isequal@4.5.0
| +-- semver@7.3.7
| | `-- lru-cache@6.0.0
| |   `-- yallist@4.0.0
| `-- typed-emitter@2.1.0
|   `-- rxjs@7.5.7
|     `-- tslib@2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're excluding your `node_modules` folder. To understand why this breaks your build, you need to know that `node_modules` is the place where all your application's dependencies (i.e. packages defined under `dependency` in your `package.json`) are stored.

Thus, when excluding this folder, you are telling Electron Builder *not to copy any of your app's dependencies*. Thus, none of these modules will be found.

Yes, `node_modules` will be increasing your app's size, but that's the tradeoff you must accept when relying on third-party software in your application. If none of the dependencies will be copied into your distributable app, none of the dependencies can be used.

The reason NPM tells you with `npm ls --production` (and the TypeScript compiler) that all these modules will be included is that, as far as NPM is concerned, your built app does not exist. NPM can run your application in debug (development) mode and in production mode, neither of which involve Electron Builder. Electron Builder simply takes you production version and packages ("builds") it for distribution.

(Note that this does not apply to `devDependencies`, such as Electron. Electron Builder will not include any of those dependencies because they're only intended to be needed if your app is run in debug mode from its source code.)

Comment: really include node_modules? I used many depedencies excluding node_modules until now. But this error did not occurred. 
`        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "query-string": "^7.0.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-lazylog": "^4.4.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
        "recoil": "^0.2.0",
        "superagent": "^6.1.0",`
I use above modules. But I have never problem excluding node_modules until now.

Comment: If this fixes your problem, as you say, then excluding the `node_modules` folder is the problem. Electron Builder will only copy the dependencies needed by your app anyway. By default, you shouldn't need to exclude anything unless there are more than your project's build files in the folder. Also, I see that you're including `desktop/*` which would be your source files, wouldn't it? I suggest you clean your build directory and try to narrow down your build configuration to the minimal viable configuration. You might be including loads of files you don't need.